# Managing windows hosts with Ansible. "winrm or requests is not installed."

Tags: powershell, ansible, redhat, centos7, winrm

I'm currently setting up Ansible on CentOS7 and I need to use it to manage some Windows machines.

I was following these two guides ([1](https://medium.com/the-sysadmin/managing-windows-machines-with-ansible-60395445069f) & [2](http://devopstechie.com/managing-windows-machines-with-ansible/)) to get this set up.

When running the command `ansible host_group -i hosts -m win_ping`

I get back an error saying:

> x.x.x.x | FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named xmltodict"}

I checked my installed python modules and I have both `winrm` and `requests`

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. There was a post I found on the RedHat forums outlining the same problem https://access.redhat.com/solutions/335668

Thanks for your time

EDIT: I also have xmltodict installed.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you have then install in the right version of python 2 vs python 3? Had similar issues before, installing with both pip and pip3 fixed it.

Comment: Hey. Something very important I failed to mention. I'm running this in a python 3.6.3 virtual environment.

Comment: I just checked the installed modules for the virtual environment and all of the modules I need are there.